# How to set gitlab Pipeline status as failed if any of stage got failed

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have created a gitlab pipeline, in which I have created 8 stages. For each stage I have set the property `**Allow_failure:true**` so that it will execute remaining stages even if any stage got failed.

Currently, if any stage got failed, then the final pipeline status is showing as "**! passed**".
I want to execute all the stages of the pipeline and if any stage got failed then I want to display pipeline status as **failed**.

**Note:** I can't change the value of property **Allow_failure**.

Please find attached Image for your reference.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no configuration given in Gitlab for this.  So we'll mostly have to handle this using scripting.

Idea:

- We add a new job at the end which validates that all previous jobs were successful.  if it sees any failure, it will fail.
- How to check?:   We leverage the files/artifacts to pass on that information.
- All the stages till the end will be executed by Gitlab (either passed or failed)

Output:
[image: Example]

Minimal Snippet:

```
jobA:
  stage: A
  allow_failure: true
  script:
    - echo "building..."
    - echo "jobA" > ./completedA
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./completedA


jobB:
  stage: B
  allow_failure: true
  script:
    - echo "testing..."
    - exit 1
    - echo "jobB" > ./completedB
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./completedB

jobC:
  stage: C
  allow_failure: true
  script:
    - echo "deplying..."
    - echo "jobC" > ./completedC
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./completedC


validate: 
  stage: Validate 
  script: 
    - |
      if [[ -f ./completedA && -f ./completedB && -f ./completedC ]]; then
      echo "All stages were completed"
      else
      echo "Stages were not completed"
      exit 1
      fi

stages:
  - A
  - B
  - C
  - Validate
```